# Logging internet usage in Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, internet, roaming-profile

We are running Windows Server 2008, with each client connecting to the internet through a Draytek router. Each client is setup with OpenDNS which blocks most websites.

There are a few limitations to OpenDNS blocking in terms of the sites the staff need to go on. For example they have a Facebook page so we can't really block Facebook. There has been an issue with staff sending various messages on Facebook to other staff, as well as on eBay etc.

We have had people in for disciplinary action over these messages and the management team would like to be able to show the staff the log if any future problems come up. It has also been added to the employment contracts that their internet usage within the company network is monitored.

Ideally, we would like to have a log of which users visited which sites. I know I can view the log within OpenDNS but that doesn't show me which user visited the site.

Is there any reasonably priced software available that would do this on a Windows 2008 Server with roaming profiles? The log would show the time, date, user and website visited.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to proxy your users internet traffic through something like [Microsoft's ISA Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/overview.aspx). Another option would be an open source solution like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). And then to get good reporting, use something like [Red Line Software's](http://www.redline-software.com/eng/download/) SurfCop or Internet Access Monitor. Both spit out executive friendly reports.

There's literally thousands of options out there, but they all generally involve directing user traffic through a proxy. You can user web traffic through the proxy with Group Policy.

None of these options require the use of roaming profiles.